# ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-forms, angular4-forms

```
<input type="email" class="form-control passname" [(ngModel)]="emailID" name="Passenger Email ID" placeholder="email" required pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$"/>
<div class="shake-tooltip-websearch-email" *ngIf="webEmailError != ''">{{webEmailError}}</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 no-padding cont-code">
  <input class="form-control passenger-contact-number" type="text"  name="contCode" value ="+91" readonly>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8 contact">
  <input class="form-control contact-number" type="text" [(ngModel)]="contactNumber" name="contact-number" placeholder="Phone"  placeholder="Mobile Number" pattern="(?<!\d)\d{10}(?!\d)" requried minlength="10" maxlength="10" required />
  <div class="shake-tooltip-web-mobile" *ngIf="webMobileError != ''">{{webMobileError}}</div>
</div>
```

I am developing a contact details page, where the user needs to enter emailID and contact number, and if the fields are left empty , then the error tooltips will show up. Everything is working fine, the email tooltip is not showing any console error, but for contact number, I am getting the

> ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute

error. Tried whatever solutions are provided in stackover flow, still nothing is working. Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you sure that's the right line? Where are you using form controls?

Comment: Yes, i am getting console error from this line only. when i check from console, it is redirecting to this line

Comment: Please, provide more code to help you !

Comment: @Luillyfe i have added additional code. Can you suggest any thing?

Answer (score -1):

It's because you have a spelling mistake on the contact-number input. You have 'required' twice and one of them is spelled 'requried'. Also you have two placeholders on that one. And although it's not relevant to this, no id's, good practice to get into.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that spelling mistake, but removing that also hasn't done the trick.